# Multiple assignment operation returns object is not iterable

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have no idea what this means:

`(success, admin_id) = login(email, password)`

The login method looks something like this:

```
def login(email, password):
    try:
        user = db.session.query(Admin).filter_by(email=email).first()        

        valid_role = 'Admin'

        if valid_role in user.role:       
            return user
    except Exception as e:
        print e

    return None
```

It returns either a TypeError: 'Admin' object is not iterable or a ValueError: too many values to unpack when I try to return just the `user.id`. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return multiple values (`tuple`) from your function you can do:

```
# when user is admin
return True, user.id
```

In the case the user is not an admin or there is an exception:

```
return False, None
```

So with `(success, admin_id) = login(email, password)`, the `success` status is returned from your function as a boolean, and the `admin_id` is either a valid user id or `None`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: So I am assigning two variables. What is the difference between having the parenthesis and not having the parenthesis?

Comment: The parenthesis  serves for readability. You can as well do without them

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns **one** object; either an `Admin()` instance:

```
if valid_role in user.role:       
    return user
```

or `None` at the end:

```
return None
```

Neither fits the expectation that the function returns *two* values, which is what this line expects:

```
(success, admin_id) = login(email, password)
```

Either adjust that line to only receive the *user*, or fix your function to return the user id and the success flag.

The latter would require that you rewrite your function to:

```
def login(email, password):
    try:
        user = db.session.query(Admin).filter_by(email=email).first()        

        valid_role = 'Admin'

        if valid_role in user.role:       
            return True, user.id
    except Exception as e:
        print e

    return False, None
```

Now your function always returns two items, either `True` and the user *id* (not the user object), or `False` and `None`.